# how to run apk remotely

Tags: android, desktop, apk

Anyone know how to run an Android APK inside a webpage?

I need my sales guys to be able to demo our Android app for potential clients without the trouble of being onsite or asking them to install the app on their phone.  Ideally I'd like to be able to send a URL with the APK running in a webpage.  My current best idea is to remote desktop into a Linux server running an Android emulator, but it's so slow and unresponsive, that's not gonna work.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want them to hit a live device, there is a VNC server for Android.  You could embed a java-based VNC viewer on the web page you suggested...

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: Give your sales guy an android device. You can find used ones for cheap (

Option 2: Email the customers the apk.  If they have allow non market applications checked in their settings they should be able to install the apk from the email.

Option 3: Same as above but allow them to download the apk from your web page.

Comment: How does option 1 help if the sales guy isn't onsite himself?  Options 2 and 3 don't work because you don't want to require a customer to supply a phone for YOUR demo.

Comment: I didn't realize your sales guy would be on site. I would just show them a video demo of the application over the internet.  Also more customers than you think may already have an Android phone. It takes up around 48% of the smart phone market share in the US.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Piecable Viewer](http://www.pieceable.com/viewer), it is used for iPad/iPhone apps (for losers). It is supposed to be implementing the same support for Android in the coming weeks. Just keep your eyes open.

Comment: the link is dead